# Laravel 7 cron job is not working on cpanel(shared hosting)

Tags: php, linux, laravel, cpanel, shared-hosting

**Here is the cron job list, I have tried with these different method but none of this working-**
[image]

**Karnel setup**
[image]

Comment: Are you getting anything from error logs?

Comment: No its not showing anything, its blank

Comment: The 2 middle entries that cd into the folder should work. Maybe on the second command (after &&) php isn't available like that. I see you used the bin path on the other two commands. Maybe replace ...&& php... with ...&& path-to-php-bin/php...??

Comment: In your Schedule method, inside your callable, $this->info() isn't available there. Should be causing errors.